# How to test if a command is a shell reserved word?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a bash script and I would like to verify if a string is a shell reserved word (like `if`, `for`, `alias`, etc...).

How can I do this?

Comment: check against the official list? http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

string="$1"

if [[ $(type "$string" 2>&1) == "$string is a shell"* ]]; then
    echo "Keyword $string is reserved by shell"
fi
```

Comment: I'd just go for the full right-anchored match personally. It isn't likely to hurt and makes things clearer. Possibly even a full match against `$string` too.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: the problem is: `type echo` => `echo is a shell builtin`, whereas `type if` => `if is a shell keyword`.

Comment: @EtanReisner What would type show if it was in that directory ?

Comment: @chatraed `if [[ $(type "$string" 2>&1) == "$string is a shell keyword" ]] || [[ $(type "$string" 2>&1) == "$string is a shell builtin" ]]`

Comment: @User112638726: are you absolutely sure that `builtin` and `keyword` are the only variations? :D

Comment: Another possibility I am thinking of is checking the exit code of `help "$string"`. But I leave it as homework for the OP! :D

Answer (score 1):

**If you want only the shell keywords, then:**

```
#!/bin/bash
string="$1"
[[ $(type -t "$string" 2>&1) == "keyword" ]] && echo reserved || echo not reserved
```

builtins won't pass this test (only keywords).

**A way of doing this with possibility of extending in various cases:**

```
#!/bin/bash
string="$1"
checkfor=('keyword' 'builtin')
for ((i=0;i<${#checkfor[@]};i++))
do
  [[ $(type -t "$string" 2>&1) == "${checkfor[$i]}" ]] && reserved=true && break || reserved=false
done
[[ $reserved == true ]] && echo reserved || echo not reserved
```

`command`, `hash`, `alias`, `type` etc.. (builtins) will pass the above test as well as keywords.

You can add other possible test conditions by adding an element into the array `checkfor`:

```
checkfor=('keyword' 'builtin' 'file' etc...)
```